# Fontconfig 2.8.0 linux fc-list no result

Tags: linux, fontconfig

I installed fontconfig by command `yum install fontconfig`. there's no error when install, but after installed, I run `fc-list`, the result is empty. Run `fc-cache` also no result. why no fonts installed? Please help.

Please see below screenshot:

```
[command output][1]

Version info: 

[root@g23leiapp03 bin]# fc-cache -V

fontconfig version 2.8.0

[root@g23leiapp03 bin]# cat /etc/redhat-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why. But copy fonts from other server works.